# How can I update multiple MySQL tables based on LIMIT on one table only?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, query-optimization

Imagine the following 3 tables:

> Table-A: | ID | A-Data | Sort-Data |
>
> Table-B: | A-ID | B-Data |
>
> Table-C: | A-ID | C-Data |

Table A has much less rows than the other 2 tables. What I have to do is break Table-A in 5 chunks using Sorting & LIMITs (20% each). Now I know I can update Table-A's data based on this limit easily. However, I can't sort and limit the other tables because they don't have the sort data - they simply have the IDs from Table A.

Is there a fast way I can do this? Do I have to collect all the IDs and use the IN operator? Do I have to join all the tables using the IDs and then update? What's the best query I could use to do this fast?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TableA AS a
JOIN TableB AS b ON a.id = b.Aid
JOIN TableC AS c ON a.id = c.Aid
JOIN (SELECT id
      FROM TableA
      ORDER BY SortData
      LIMIT 5) AS asorted ON a.id = asorted.id
SET a.adata = x, b.bdata = y, c.cdata = z
```

Comment: Hi, this query takes forever to run on not too big of a dataset. Why is that?

Comment: Do you have indexes on all the fields used in the joins?

Comment: yep. still takes a long time.

Comment: can you make a sqlfiddle with some sample data?